# Is there another way to print multiple list elements where the list index increases by a given amount with each print?

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing hundreds of integers. I need to take 34 integers at a time, starting from the beginning of the list and print the integers in separate rows of 34.

The problem is that I have to use multiple `print (list[x:y])` and continuously change the value for x and y.

I've tried specifying each index within the list to be printed, however, this is impractical since the list may contain hundreds of values.

```py
integer = [
    3,23,12,34,2,4,7,11,14,1,9,17,12,1,0,5,4,3,2,4,8,1,12,15,18,17,14,23,12,0,0
    ,12,34,2,21,22,24,23,1,0,4,7,3,13,16,15,3,5,11,22,9,14,20,16,3,6,2,0,10,1,12
    ,18,9,9,23,6,2,18,14,1,0,3,5,17,13,12,5,6,9,0,1,2,19,20,2,3,5,7,15,19,2,4,10
    ,15,18,17,2,6,5,3,6,12,15,18,12,15,6,20,0,9,4,1,5,4,3,7,9,0,12,3,5,7,8,17,19
    ,21,0,1,2,7,7,7,5,4,3,8,19,12,16,0,2,4,7,8,4,12,12,9,3,20,2,21,3,5,8,9,12,17
    ,8,7,3,4,6,3,14,18,21,4,3,9,19,19,3,6,8,7,13,14,18,13,15,3,4,8,7,12
]

print (integer[0:34])
print (integer[35:69])
print (integer[70:104])
```

Output:

```
[3, 23, 12, 34, 2, 4, 7, 11, 14, 1, 9, 17, 12, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 8, 1, 12, 15, 18, 17, 14, 23, 12, 0, 0, 12, 34, 2]
[22, 24, 23, 1, 0, 4, 7, 3, 13, 16, 15, 3, 5, 11, 22, 9, 14, 20, 16, 3, 6, 2, 0, 10, 1, 12, 18, 9, 9, 23, 6, 2, 18, 14]
[0, 3, 5, 17, 13, 12, 5, 6, 9, 0, 1, 2, 19, 20, 2, 3, 5, 7, 15, 19, 2, 4, 10, 15, 18, 17, 2, 6, 5, 3, 6, 12, 15, 18]
```

Comment: need to use loops: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-python/

Comment: Are you intentionally missing out a value (e.g. 21) between each line?

Comment: Is the entire list guaranteed to be a multiple of 34?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your expected output doesn't intentionally skip a value as shown, the following will print groups of 34 elements in a single line:

```
wholeLines = len(integer) // 34 * 34
for i in range( 0,wholeLines,34 ):
    print(integer[i:i+34])
print( integer[wholeLines:] )
```

If you do not need to print out the remaining portion of the final line then you can omit the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for an easy way to print chunks of size `chunk_size` of a list, use the following one-line list comprehension:

`[print(data[chunk_size * index : chunk_size * index + chunk_size]) for index in range((len(data) // chunk_size) + 1)]`

Change `chunk_size` to represent however large you would like your chunks to be.

Example:

```py
In[2]: x = list(range(35))
In[3]: x
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
In[4]: chunk_size = 9
In[5]: [print(x[chunk_size * index : chunk_size * index + chunk_size]) for index in range((len(x) // chunk_size) + 1)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

so you are looking to iteratively take 34 elements -- I'll assume you want to print the last elements of the list even if there aren't a full 34. The tool to use here is a Loop. Inside that for loop, you want to print 34 elements based on a current index, like so:

```
print intlist(n:n+34)
```

okay, so your iteration limits. the simplest way to do this is with a do-while loop (and remember to incremement your index variable each loop):

```
n=0
while n < len(intlist):
    print intlist(n:n+34)
    n += 34
```

there's a bug here, though. it won't print the last section of the list -- because you will get an `IndexOutoFRange` exception (when n+34 is too big). To fix that, you can wrap this in an try-except block, which will handle the special case by printing to the end of your list:

```
n=0
while n < len(intlist):
    try:
        print intlist(n:n+34)
    except:
        print intlist(n:)
    n += 34
```